# Shell Script: Search maillog for each folder name in directory

Tags: shell

I have a folder with subfolders in it:

```
/example.org
  /account1
  /account2
  /account3
```

I want to search /var/log/maillog, /var/log/maillog.1, /var/log/maillog.2, etc., for occurrences of the account folders names.

If there is no occurrences, I want to log it to a file.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with grep.

first you have to get the patterns you want to "search". those accounts (sub-dir names in your case). You could use `find` or `ls` to get those sub-dir names, each per line. 
for example: `ls -l |grep "^d"|awk '{print $8}'`

so the pattern file looks like: (say, saved as pattern.txt)

```
account1
account2
account3
```

then you could :

```
grep -FL -f pattern.txt /var/log/maillog*
```

this will list those maillog* files which don't contain accounts in your pattern.txt.

if you want those output to be saved as a file, just redirect with `> file`

Note that all above were not tested, just an idea of how to solve the problem. hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Definitely gave me an idea on how to proceed. :-)